# change the Form Field using Twilio and parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, twilio

I am using parse.com and Twilio to send SMS from an application.

when I place on the 'Form' field the twilio number i purchased it send the SMS with no issues.

SMS are sent to a country that does support alphanumeric sender ID.

When trying to place a text string instead am getting the following error:
'The 'From' number XXXXXXXX is not a valid phone number or shortcode.'

```
var twilio = require('twilio')(classes.twilio.accountSid,    classes.twilio.authToken);

twilio.sendSms({
        to:'+'+ phoneNumber,
        from: classes.twilio.phoneNumber,
        body: newMessage
});
```

when I tried to use Twilio API explorer it send the message with the alphanumeric sender ID

any ideas what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
In main.js:

```
var twilio = require('cloud/twilio.js');
twilio.initialize('XXXXX', 'YYYY');
twilio.sendSMS({
                  From : "YourString",
                  To : request.params.number,
                  Body : "Your message"}, 
                   { 
                    success : function(httpResponse) {
                      response.success("Message sent!");}, 
                    error : function(httpResponse) {
                        response.error("Opps Error " + httpResponse);}
                  });
```

add a file called twilio.js in your cloud folder and paste the code blow in twilio.js.

```
var APIEndPoint = 'api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/';
var accountSid = '';
var authToken = '';

module.exports = {
  initialize: function(sid, token) {
    accountSid = sid;
    authToken = token;
    return this;
  },

  sendSMS: function(params, options) {
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      method: "POST",
      url: 'https://' + accountSid + ':' + authToken + '@' + APIEndPoint + 'Accounts/' + accountSid + '/Messages',
      body: params,
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        options.success(httpResponse);
    }, function(httpResponse) {
        options.error(httpResponse);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: H, when I try to use twilio.sendSMS I get the following: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sendSMS', could it be related to the parse version ?

Comment: By the way have you managed to use the FORM field with a different language ? other than English ? when I tried I got the following : <Message>The 'From' number ×¡××××ª ××××§××ª is not a valid phone number or shortcode.</Message>. thx for all you help

Comment: Yes I tried another language but it had latin characters only and it worked fine. Is this ×¡××××ª ××××§××ª alphanumeric?

Comment: I tried using Hebrew letters and I got those marks and not my string.

Comment: What to do if I want to make a call through Twilio with the above code?